# Checking the existance for a File in a Makefile

Tags: makefile

I have been trying to check the existence of a file in a Makefile without success:

I tried:

```
.PHONY test:
ifeq ($(shell test -e "/opt/local/bin/lame" && echo -n "yes"),"yes")
    @echo 'File exists'
else
    @echo 'File does not exist'
endif
```

I always get "File does not exist" when I run `make test`.  And yes the file does exist!

I also tried the following:

```
.PHONY test:
ifeq ($(shell echo -n "yes"),"yes")
    @echo 'File exists'
else
    @echo 'File does not exist'
endif
```

Again, I always get "File does not exist" when I run `make test`.
So I must not be using the conditional test right.

what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to check for the existence of the file in a Makefile using `wildcard`.  See below:

```
.PHONY test:
ifneq ("$(wildcard /opt/local/bin/lame)","")
    @echo 'File exists'
else
    @echo 'File does not exist'
endif
```

I am still confused why my precious attempt did not work.